# Foundation Off-canvas menu scroll

Tags: canvas, zurb-foundation

I have a off-canvas menu in my page that uses foundation. The problem here is if the page has scroll the off-canvas menu will have the same. How can I have a scroll only for the menu (if the lines are bigger than the container) and disable the scroll of the page, like the bootstrap does?

Thank you

Comment: The problem with that is the footer is not visible

Comment: i have amended it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOLeVP?editors=110

Comment: I tested that in Iphone and the page scrool is little bit sticky (don't flow) and also when the menu is open, the page on the side also has scroll (menu has one scroll and page also has)

Comment: can you code at all? just adjust the article overflow-y to hidden

Comment: Was the first thing I did!!!